# Specific Android Phone and OS causing errors with my app

Tags: android, testing

I recently released my app to the Google Play community. The team and myself tested the app on  Gingerbread, jellybean, and kitkat. All were either Samsungs or Nexus. Now we have someone getting a crash on a Motorolla Droid Bionic, Android version 4.1.2.

My app required wifi (not Cell data) connection which is not possible with androids emulator. I am in the process of installing android on VirtualBox but I don't know if this will allow me to identify the problem.

Should I be this concerned? This is my first app and I want to make sure it works for everyone? This app is for controlling a home appliance so I feel like we need to make sure that it works, but I'm not sure how to really get accurate test results and error messages.

What do other developers do to emulate accurately specific phones and OS versions?

thanks for any advise and help.

Comment: you can see the detailed stacktrace in your Google Developer console if someone report the bug.

Comment: On the google play store?

Comment: Are you the publisher of the app?

Comment: No the company I wrote the app for is. But I can get them to send me anything from the app store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask for the "`Stack Traces`" reported in "`Crashes & ANRs`" section of your application in `Google play Developer Console` to have more details about the problem.

[image]